# Simplify this boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra

$$
\begin{align}
&\lnot x_1(x_2\land\lnot x_3\lor x_3)\lor x_1(\lnot x_2\land\lnot x_3\lor x_2\land x_3)\\
&=\lnot x_1\land x_2\land\lnot x_3\lor\lnot x_1\land x_3\lor x_1\land\lnot x_2\land\lnot x_3\lor x_1\land x_2\land x_3
\end{align}
$$

Is it possible to simplify the above?

Comment: What are "$\ast$" and "+" mean here?

Comment: @user35603: meanings added

Comment: and what does $x1x2$ mean?

Comment: @Kaster: I don't see anywhere x1x2, but why you ask about the meaning? Is the way I write those wrong? What's the correct way?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit.

Comment: @Luka you have something like $x_1 (...)$, so I wonder what's the difference between $x_1(...)$ and $x_1 * (...)$

Comment: It's the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further simplify by using [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) method. Before that, you must transform your expression into its [CDNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form_%28Boolean_algebra%29), so you get:
$$\neg x_1 x_2 \neg x_3 \vee \neg x_1 x_2 x_3 \vee \neg x_1 \neg x_2 x_3 \vee x_1 \neg x_2 \neg x_3 \vee x_1 x_2 x_3.$$

Finally, the simplified expression looks like this:
$$x_1 \neg x_2 \neg x_3 \vee \neg x_1 x_2 \vee \neg x_1 x_3 \vee x_2 x_3.$$